# understanding commit and merge

Tags: git, merge, git-commit

I am a little bit confused as to how a branch needs to be merged once work is completed.

So I have created a repo which has the following: I've based each branch according to issue/feature.

```
Master
Development

branch-1 - jira issue 1
branch-2 - jira issue 2
branch-3 - jira issue 3
branch-4 - jira issue 4
```

Issue 1 was created off of Development branch. Once I've completed work in the first branch I then created branch 2 while still being on branch-1 like so.

```
git checkout -b branch-2
```

I started working on branch-2 and then completed the work needed to be done on that issue.

But I am sitting with a problem where branch-1 has eg. 8 commits and branch-2 has 15 commits. I'm guessing there will be merge conflicts here. So if I were to merge these branches once they've been reviewed. How do I proceed? Help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if branch-2 is based off of branch-1 and no further commits have been done on branch-1 since, there should be no conflicts between the two.

Comment: Okay. So that means that branch-1 will basically build on the changes from branch 2 if branch 2 is a few commits ahead of branch 1?

Comment: That means that if you merge b2 into b1, that will be a fast-forward merge (b1 will only be advanced to the commit pointed to by b2)

Comment: Okay thanks. That helps me to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

Git is very friendly to conflicts. With a little patience you will understand it.

The procedure is like this (On branch2):

```
git checkout branch1
git merge branch2
```

Git will show you the conflicts (if you have them).
An example of conflict will be like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
this code is old
=======
this is my new code
>>>>>>> branch1
```

You could choose between bot lines.

Don't be afraid, conflicts are very common and you should learn to understand and fix them.

Comment: Thanks @VictorLopez